# How can I use the layout I prepared in the DialogPreference？

Tags: android-preferences

I want to create a new class to customize dialogpreference.Though I try to many methods,they all didn't work. And I find a way to  use the layout prepared as the layout of dialog in the dialogpreference on the site as follow: [How to access widgets in a custom DialogPreference with a inflated layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722531/how-to-access-widgets-in-a-custom-dialogpreference-with-a-inflated-layout).

When I try to use the layout like this: `setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.address_dialog);` But it didn't work.Can you help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It is better late then never :) and I think the answer to this question already exists somewhere on the SO.

You should write something like this in your :

```
@Override
public View onCreateDialogView() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.city_select_dialog, null);

    // {Your code here}

    return view;
}
```