# Android: Creating custom preference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

Is it possible to create an individual preference in an `PreferenceScreen`?

I would like to code color settings like that:

[image: Color Preference]

I know that choosing the color is easy realizable with the `ListPreference`, but it would be awesome with that kind of "checkboxes".

Answer (score 93):

The Android Developer page only shows how to make a `DialogFragment`.  It's still possible to customise the appearance of a `Preference` item though.  In your XML you have to declare the root element as `android:id="@android:id/widget_frame`, and then declare `TextView` as `android:title` and `android:summary`.  You can then declare other elements you want to appear in the layout.  Here's an example showing a `SeekBar` which you could easily adapt to a multi-checkbox colour chooser.

**seekbar_preference.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.SearchResult.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/summary"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.SearchResult.Subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Summary" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in a class that derives from `Preference`, override the `onCreateView()` method:

**SeekbarPreference.java**

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView( ViewGroup parent )
{
  LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
  return li.inflate( R.layout.seekbar_preference, parent, false);
}
```

Then in the preferences.xml file use the preference:

**preferences.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <com.example.SeekbarPreference
        android:key="pref_max_volume"
        android:title="@string/max_volume" />
    <com.example.SeekbarPreference
        android:key="pref_balance"
        android:title="@string/balance" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

This gives a preference that looks as follows:

[image: Seekbar preference item]

You can easily adapt this method to show multiple checkboxes on a row as was in the original question.

Comment: +1 for <com.example.SeekbarPreference... I was skipping package qualification but was building on official guidance, developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom,  linked below by @tbkn23 which missed that step.

Comment: I wonder how to make such a custom preference with colors disabled.. anyone?

Comment: in this example `onCreateView()` called twice, and you should call `super.onCreate()`

Comment: Note that the layout for `SeekBarPreference` can actually be found here: `<andorid-sdk>/platforms/android-24/data/res/layout/preference_widget_seekbar.xml`. The Android layouts do not use the `widget_frame` id as root elements, why do you say that has to be done? Actually, there is a comment in the XML saying "Preference should place its actual preference widget here." which comes *after* the title and summary `TextView`s but before a `LinearLayout` with id `widget_frame'.

Comment: Hello Thank you for this wonderful guide, i have one concern if i want to change the values of the Title and the summary and implement a click listener on the layout how its done ? thank you!

Comment: WARN: this sol is based on old preferences. New API (from v7 support lib) use little bit diff approach. See below stackoverflow.com/a/33842737

Comment: In order to match the layout to the rest of the built-in preferences, you can find the latest androidx preference layout here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/preference/preference/res/layout/preference.xml copy it, modify it and watch for changes when you update AndroidX.

Answer (score 50):

This is how I do it, using support library [`preference-v7`](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-preference).

- Extend  [`Preference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html) and override [`onBindViewHolder()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html#onBindViewHolder(android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceViewHolder)). This method allows you to get references to your preference's view via the [`ViewHolder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) object.
- Inflate your custom view using either [`setWidgetLayoutResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html#setWidgetLayoutResource(int)) or [`setLayoutResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html#setLayoutResource(int)) in constructor.
- Disable the default click behaviour of the whole preference view, and only allow custom views inside to be clickable.

[image: preference]

**layout/preference_theme.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/theme_light" ... />
    <Button android:id="@+id/theme_dark"... />
    <Button android:id="@+id/theme_sepia"... />
    <Button android:id="@+id/theme_green"... />
</LinearLayout>
```

**PreferenceTheme.java** (custom Preference class)

```
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceViewHolder;

public class PreferenceTheme extends Preference {

    public PreferenceTheme(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public PreferenceTheme(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_theme);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
        holder.itemView.setClickable(false); // disable parent click
        View button = holder.findViewById(R.id.theme_dark);
        button.setClickable(true); // enable custom view click
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // persist your value here
            }
        });
        // the rest of the click binding
    }
}
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Reading">
        <example.com.preference.PreferenceTheme
            android:key="pref_theme"
            android:title="Theme"
            android:defaultValue="light" />
        ...
    </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Can you give me a clue how to create and use `PreferenceTheme` instance in the `PreferenceActivity` with constructor parameters (context and attrs) and `findPreference`?

Comment: I wrote a blog post about using `preference-v7` here if you are interested http://www.hidroh.com/2015/11/30/building-custom-preferences-v7/

Comment: How can I apply this if I use androidx instead of the support libs?

Answer (score 8):

Creating a custom preference is similar to creating a fragment or other UI components, by defining views and actions.

Android developers has a good guide on creating settings, which includes a section for creating custom preferences: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28537969)

Comment: Considering this answer is from 2013, and android released dozens of updates to its API, that might actually be a good thing :) But I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 6):

You can create your custom layout for preference and you can set it in `android:layout` attribute in Preference in res/xml like this:

```
<Preference
    ......................
    android:layout="@layout/your_layout" />
```

Or you can use an Activity instead of preference

Comment: if we are trying to create a custom edittextpreference then using android android:layout="@layout/your_layout" will not show it in a dialogue but there on the main screen itself.

Comment: Something i dont get is that how will i like the for example spinner inside your_layout with the preference ?

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Comment: if i want to update your_layout element how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Or a better alternative will be to extend the DialogPreference class. You can set a color picker widget as the dialog view and get the positive result inside the extended preference itself. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533078/timepicker-in-preferencescreen) is a similar question, but it is very useful for your scenario.