# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo.{MapsActivity} sometimes

Tags: android, kotlin, runtime-error, runtimeexception

Here is my StackTrace, the error apears when I try to enter to do the intent to my Maps Activity, but it not seems to appear always, If I uninstall the app, then it goes. And if I try to implement changes in the activity code (custom markers...) then sometimes it crashes

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.buigues.ortola.touristics:layout/activity_maps: Binary XML file line #8 in com.buigues.ortola.touristics:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.buigues.ortola.touristics:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070016 type #0x3 is not valid
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources.java:827)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ax.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213918100@21.39.18 (150700-0):5)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fh.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213918100@21.39.18 (150700-0):6)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bo.az(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213918100@21.39.18 (150700-0):16)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cr.o(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213918100@21.39.18 (150700-0):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213918100@21.39.18 (150700-0):22)
        at dx.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213918100@21.39.18 (150700-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzH(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzau.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zae.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:386)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
2021-11-13 17:02:57.854 16597-16597/com.buigues.ortola.touristics E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.buigues.ortola.touristics.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(ActivityMapsBinding.java:36)
        at com.buigues.ortola.touristics.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(ActivityMapsBinding.java:30)
        at com.buigues.ortola.touristics.ui.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.kt:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The maps layout (autogenerated by Android when you create a Google Maps Activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MapsActivity" />
```

Comment: The error says that line 8 of the XML file is generating an error. A resource ID was not found. `tools:context` is line 8 remove it and see what happens

Comment: Is it debug or release build?

Comment: I looked at my errors, maybe they help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64225190/2914140, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53761958/2914140.