# Load preferences from DB

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have a set of **preference fragments** (ringtone, threshold,...) for each entity. So I would rather load the relevant contents **from** the **DB** (ContentProvider) than from SharedPrefences.
What is the best way to do this?
Is there a way to intercept the loading/saving process from/to SharedPreferences?

If possible I would like to avoid a custom layout, because built in preference features are much faster and easier to implement.

Comment: I don't see why you want to use a database instead of SharedPreferences, can you clarify that a bit?

Comment: Because I have a list of entities that are loaded from the DB (and synced over the net). And the prefs need to be set for each entity individually.

Comment: If the prefs need to be set for each entity individually and sent over the internet then you need to make provisions for these in your database schema.

Comment: what exactly do you want to store in DB? the selected values by the user or the possible options the user can pick among?

Comment: My users can load a list of places (from the DB) and set e.g. an alarm ringtone for each place. (This is a customer's requirements.)

Comment: You can also shoot mosquitoes with a cannon, if you like.

Comment: override `SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences()` in your custom `Preference` so that it returns your own implementation of `SharedPreferences` interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the question was to imitate the look and feel from the built in preferences framework the best possible way.

Thanks @pskink for pointing out how this can be done by implementing your own SharedPreferences!

I finally took [this proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108609/android-creating-custom-preference) as a starting point for a custom layout because I needed some controls that are not provided out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

From a Mobile [UX](http://developer.android.com/training/best-ux.html) (User experience) perspective this is a really bad idea. Since a DB access yields a bigger UI latency in comparison to the simple key-value-store-accesses the user experience will suffer a great deal from this.
Go for the standard approach, and write a convenience wrapper class instead where you can pass in your objects that can contain a whole preference.