# Android: Matching Preference Listview item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-preferences

I need help with styling my custom preference according to the app style(sheet).

I've created a custom preference that shows two settings side-by-side (first name and last name). All is fine, I can edit them using a custom dialog etc, but I am having trouble styling it to look like the other list preferences.

Image below shows what I am trying to do.

[image: View list]

I'd like to make the top preference (my custom one) look like the bottom one (straight from settings.xml). As you can see the padding, text color, size etc are all difference; this is possibly because "my" preference uses Linear Layouts + Text Views and not a standard preference list view item.

My custom preference XML came from this answer [Android: Creating custom preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108609/android-creating-custom-preference)

This is my app theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and this is the code for my preference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="2"
              android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/firstname"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.SearchResult.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/setting_firstname" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/firstname_data"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.SearchResult.Subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="moo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastname"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.SearchResult.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/setting_lastname" />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastname_data"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.SearchResult.Subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Moo" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have two questions basically:

1. What is / where can I find the XML that creates a preference list item - is it is standard list view item or its own custom XML?
2. How do I make my preference look like a standard one?

I tried to assign android:id="@android:id/widget_frame" to the linear layout (as suggested in the Stackoverflow answer above)

Also tried various style= on the Text views (style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.SearchResult.Subtitle") but I don't know if this is correct and what other options are available

Other info

My fullname preference is just standard code :

```
public class FullnamePreference extends DialogPreference {
```

My settings.xml contains this:

```
    <com.example.Settings.FullnamePreference
            android:key="fullname"/>
    <Preference
            android:key="version"
            android:summary="@string/setting_version_summary"
            android:title="@string/setting_version" />
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, your text is dark because you are basing your app theme on a light theme (light theme, hence dark text).  Try basing your theme on `Theme.Appcompat` (a dark theme to match preferences) for starters.

Comment: If you really want a light theme for your app with just the dark theme for preferences, you can add a dark theme based on `Theme.AppCompat` to your styles, then assign it to the layout using the attribute `app:theme="R.style.AppThemeDark"`on your layout.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. But even if I change the theme, the text color will change, not the size, layout and spacing which is my real problem