# Multiple CheckBox with a PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm a student,I'm new in the Android World and I'm trying to develop my first application.
I'm in troubles with my Preferences.
I would like to have two Checkboxpreference in the same line, that modify two difference preference values, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45cu5.png).
This is the part of code that I'm actually using in my preference.xml to show two checkbox, but they aren't in the same line:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    

         <PreferenceCategory>

           <CheckBoxPreference
              android:key="key1"
              android:title="Title"
              android:summary="Summary" >
           </CheckBoxPreference>

           <CheckBoxPreference
              android:summary="Another summary"
              android:key="key2">
           </CheckBoxPreference>

         </PreferenceCategory>
      </PreferenceScreen>
```

Is it possible?
Thanks,

Giacomo

Comment: are they part of a activity or of a listview or something else?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom you should use this guide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Creating custom preference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108609/android-creating-custom-preference)

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX they're part of a preference.xml file that is used by a PreferenceFragment

Comment: @xklakoux thanks for the suggestion, I don't know why but that solution doesn't work in my code...

Comment: @xklakoux the two checkboxes modify two different fields in my preference fragment, this is the problem