# Is there a way to put a clickable icon next to a Preference?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

I am remaking our custom preferences screen into PreferencesScreen.

We currently have several settings, for example checkboxes, with a questionmark icon next to it that users can click to get information about the setting.

The built-in preferences have "setIcon" which works, but it does not seem possible to make them clickable.

Is the only solution to make totally custom layouts for my preference, or is there some other way to have a clickable image or icon next to my preference rows?

Comment: have you checked out this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108609/android-creating-custom-preference

Comment: Thanks, that's a custom layout as i mentioned above. I was just wondering if there was some built-in way to make a clickable icon.

Comment: I don't think so it is possible.. you could make  `CustomView` which would be clickable and add it in `custom layout`.