# Styling SeekBarPreference to be consistent with SwitchPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-styles

I have the following preferences in my `preferences.xml`:

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:summary="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet"
    android:title="Frobulate" />
<SeekBarPreference android:title="Marglins"/>
<SwitchPreference android:title="Bromzuling" />
```

The problem with this is that this renders `Marglins` with a very different style as the titles of the `SwitchPreference`s:

[image: 1]]

Is there something I can put in my `styles.xml` to make the titles look the same in font size, color, alignment etc.?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108609/android-creating-custom-preference) and [this](https://robobunny.com/wp/?p=190)

Comment: I'm going to shamelessly plug [my library](https://github.com/consp1racy/android-support-preference) where all the half-baked stuff should work out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

In your theme, try setting

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
```

In my mock-up, this shows the following:

[image]

This is using **com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1**. Since this is the look that you are looking for, use this library if you can.

*Make sure that you are consistently using the preference support library and not mixing things up; otherwise, things make not look/work as expected.*

Here is a small app that demonstrates styling of the SeekBar preference. The app doesn't really do anything other than display the preferences. This app show the same display as shown above.

**AndroidManifest.xml**
Nothing fancy here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.preferencecustomlayout">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.example.preferencecustomlayout.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <!-- Theme for the preferences -->
            <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

**app_preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switchPreference1"
        android:summary="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet"
        android:title="Frobulate" />

    <android.support.v7.preference.SeekBarPreference
        android:key="seekBarPreference"
        android:title="Marglins" />

    <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="switchPreference1"
        android:title="Bromzuling" />

</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

**MainActivity.java**
Notice all the "v7" imports at the top. Don't let these get away. If things aren't working, check that you are still using the support library.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment preferenceFragment = new PrefsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.prefContainer, preferenceFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**
Just a home for the preference fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/prefContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.preferencecustomlayout.MainActivity" />
```

As for eliminating the numeric display from the seekbar, that is going to be a little more involved. According to the [SeekBarPreference documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/SeekBarPreference):

> The seekbar value view can be shown or disabled by setting showSeekBarValue attribute to true or false, respectively.

Unfortunately, setting this value in the `app_preferences.xml` file gives an "is private" error. There is also no public method, that I have seen, to set the internal variable that controls this. You could subclass `SeekBarPreference`, override `onBindViewHolder()` as follows:

**MySeekBarPreference.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceViewHolder;
import android.support.v7.preference.SeekBarPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MySeekBarPreference extends SeekBarPreference {
    public MySeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public MySeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MySeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MySeekBarPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder view) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(view);
        TextView seekBarValueTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_value);
        seekBarValueTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

The above custom seek bar preference class will just get rid of the seek bar value. Change the seek bar definition in `app_preferences.xml` to:

```
<com.example.preferencestyleseekbar.MySeekBarPreference
    android:key="seekBarPreference"
    android:title="Marglins" />
```

and you will see that the value is no longer shown.

Preferences are generally a mess. I have found a very good [series of articles](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-1-5959aa49337c) by Jakob Ulbrich regarding preferences and getting them to work and look like material design. You may find it helpful to check them out.

Comment: Currently it doesn't show a numeric value, only a slider, and I'd like to keep it that way; is that possible with this theme you recommend?

Comment: I tried adding the `preferenceTheme` item to the `style` that is specified in my manifest for the preference activity, and it doesn't seem to change anything. Can you show a `styles.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml` fragment showing how it should all hang together?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to use com.android.support:preference-v14 instead of v7. This allowed me to use PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material, which otherwise was not accessible.